# How to connect/debug Firebase connectivity on a React-Native Android App

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to implement the sample react-native firebase app posted in a popular [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html).

My initialization looks like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDKTvsqGoMn9ksXxaujXqciM2M5R0tuZlw",
  authDomain: "my-awesome-project-a8216.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://my-awesome-project-a8216.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "my-awesome-project-a8216.appspot.com",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

My code looks like this:

```
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
      };
      this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items');
    }
    getRef() {
      console.log("Reference "+firebaseApp.database().ref().child('items'));
        return firebaseApp.database().ref();
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
      }
  _renderItem(item) {
      return (
        <ListItem item={item}  onPress = {() => {

        }}/>
      );

    }

    listenForItems(itemsRef) {
      console.log("Came 1");

    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      console.log("Came Here");

      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        console.log("my data "+ child.key);
        items.push({
          title: child.val().title,
          _key: child.key
        });
      });

      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
      });

    });
  }
```

In the above code, there are two `console.log` debug statements in the `listenForItems` function.

```
console.log("Came 1");
console.log("Came Here");
```

I see "Came 1" on the chrome console and do not see "Came Here"
The Network Tab in the chrome console does not show any outbound calls to the firebase url referenced in the code.
There are no errors on the console as such leaving me no clue to debug whats going on...

I appreciate all your answers. Thanks :)

Comment: does the console.log in the getRef() method get called? What does it say ?

Comment: Yes it does. See this: Reference https://my-awesome-project-a8216.firebaseio.com/items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to debug more easily, you can do `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);` right after your firebase conf.

Firebase 3.3 seems to have trouble integrating with react-native.
Waiting for a fix to be released, you can downgrade to the same dependencies used in the tutorial :

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "15.2.1",
    "react-native": "^0.29.0"
}
```

This should fix your problem for now.

Also make sure that you have allowed public access in your firebase settings. Go to project > database > rules.

Replace

```
// These rules require authentication
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

with

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

See this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: Hi, That did not help. Firstly I do not see any active network traffic between the App and Firebase.

Comment: Interesting. I reproduced your code on my machine and that's what solved it. What versions of react native / firebase are you using ?

Comment: Firebase 3.3.0 and React-Native 0.32. Here is the link for my GIT Repo for a better look. Feel free to check it out. https://github.com/mva1991/AwesomeProject

Comment: Dago, Thanks a lot. Actually, Changing the rules did help. I had a bug in my code that was not rendering the data properly.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and the fix was the rules. The default rules for a new bucket are `auth != null` which does not work if you haven't setup any authentication yet. Thanks for the good answer!

Comment: And how does it enable debugging by making  `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`? Is it going to output anything on console? I am trying to see if it's connecting or not.